# Discord.py Why removing roles doesn't work?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Giving roles work correct. But absolutely copied "on_reaction_remove" don't give any results, even exceptions. I tried to choose reactions in second account, yes, bot gave a role, but when I removed reaction bot did not do anything:/

```
import discord
from discord import utils
from discord.ext import commands
import config

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '#')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(client.user.name))

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if str(reaction.message.channel) == 'giving-roles':
        try:
            channel = reaction.message.channel
            role = utils.get(user.guild.roles, id = config.ROLES[str(reaction)])

            await user.add_roles(role)
            print(f'[SUCCESS] Role [{config.ROLES[str(reaction)]} for [{user}] was added ')

        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

@client.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, user):
    if str(reaction.message.channel) == 'giving-roles':
        try:
            channel = reaction.message.channel
            role = utils.get(user.guild.roles, id = config.ROLES[str(reaction)])

            await user.remove_roles(role)
            print(f'[SUCCESS] Role [{config.ROLES[str(reaction)]} for [{user}] was removed ')

        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

# RUN
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: If you remove the try and except, does it produce any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this a while back and I found using `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` and `on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)` worked better.

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id

#Soft Ocean   
    if message_id == 677963887122841625: # This can be changed but i was using an individual message
        guild_id = payload.guild_id 
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds) # This gets the guild

        if payload.emoji.name == 'tick': #This is the name of the emoji that is used
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Soft Ocean') # Enter the role name here

        if role is not None: # If role exists
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members) #Gets the member
            if member is not None: # Checks if member is real
                await member.add_roles(role) # Gives the role
            else:
                print("Member not found")
        else:
            print("Role not found")

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id

#Soft Ocean   
    if message_id == 677963887122841625:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'tick':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Soft Ocean')

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
            else:
                print("Member not found")
        else:
            print("Role not found")
```

Comment: Thx, it was very helpful. But instead of 
member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
I used: 
member = await(await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)).fetch_member(payload.user_id)

Answer (score 0):

hard worker, I certainly understand that you have already solved your problem, but I still found a way to solve it much easier than our comrades. For example see and taste this code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member): 
    Channel = bot.get_channel(id ur channel)
    if not member.bot:
        if reaction.message.channel == Channel:
            if reaction.emoji == 'ur emoji':
                zxc = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="zxc")
                await member.add_roles(zxc)
        else:
            pass
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_remove(reaction, member):
    Channel = bot.get_channel(ur id )
    if reaction.message.channel == Channel:
        if reaction.emoji == 'ur emoji':
            zxc = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="zxc")
            await member.remove_roles(zxc)
```

Of course, brother, I understand everything (absolutely everything), the code is primitive   (well, easy), but he will solve your problem like a finger on the asphalt (that is, for one or two (I hope you understand (I'm just not an Omerican))). lets giritTT